# Why doesn't the 'Add' type satisfy the constraint 'number'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried practicing type gymnastics with typescript.And my goal is Implementing mathematical operations on numeric literals.
First of all,I implemented type `BuildArray`:

```
type BuildArray<
    Length extends number, 
    Ele = unknown, 
    Arr extends unknown[] = []
> = Arr['length'] extends Length 
        ? Arr 
        : BuildArray<Length, Ele, [...Arr, Ele]>;
type MyArray = BuildArray<3> // type MyArray = [unknown, unknown, unknown]
```

Then,I implemented type `Add`:

```
type Add<Num1 extends number, Num2 extends number> = 
    [...BuildArray<Num1>, ...BuildArray<Num2>]['length']
type AddResult = Add<2, 5> // type AddResult = 7
```

However, when I tried implementing `Multiply` based on `Add`,it occured error:

```
type Multiply<Num1 extends number, Num2 extends number, Counter extends number = 0, Result extends number = 0> =
    Counter extends Num2?
    Result:
    Multiply<Num1, Num2, Add<Counter, 1>, Add<Num1, Result>>
type MultiplyResult = Multiply<4, 5> // type MultiplyResult = 20
```

Though the result is correct, it occured compile error:

[image]

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgSwDYBMCCAnDBDEAeAWACgpSoAZCAOwHNgALKCAD2GpQGcoq4BbAIwgYANFGJkoAUSTQAvFDhUA1lQD2AdyqjxZTBiat2XRSo1UA2gF0o8q8QB8NqHvMByGbQavrLNlU4U1HSMOhKkAPzOWGIkYaQAXLCIqHq4eJSe9KLSEKLmAHSFetkylvYA3MSgkFAAsiCpIE7wyOhYaQDMjgD03VDV0PWNTuYmapqiY2aTyuNUlsRV4NBoKCh4AHJ8AIwGfgE8AkKiW7wATHtG3HyCGI7yoVAFhS0p7fin2-aihfmvbTgPnwzvZLG4PMFvEsaqsUAAlCAcOBIYBOWF4M6iACsPT6A2cawRSJRTgA7IsiPjasjgAgwEggbxdr4rodbidgZd-Fw2ccoABhVSKNj6Fnc65HfTyAAMoiJNK5BxuQic0vuj0FwpVYoCpzO4Ue8pR8Ue1JRdIZmx2HPOonRmqoItEXztaytTLliJp9ns0MGNItICNqPkZtp9PwABZsbj+ss6gGI8GnGdpUA)

Can someone please tell me why this compilation error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are passing `Counter` in `Add<Counter, 1>`, it's extending the type `number`, but it's still unknown number. When it's passed from `Add` to `BuildArray`, you then have this check:

```
Arr['length'] extends Length?
```

and based on that check, you have different expected types `Arr` or `BuildArray<Length, Ele, [...Arr, Ele]>` which will again have the same issue.

Going back to `Add`, in the case of unknown number, TypeScript won't achieve that this `length` prop is the prop of an `Array`, which is already a `number`.

So you get the value correctly, but the type itself is still not sure that this is a `number`, because the check `Arr['length'] extends Length?` in `BuildArray` is not resolved to know that the `Arr` is the type that we are trying to access `length` from.

I am not sure if this was clear enough, but TL;DR: To achieve what you need with the minimum changes, you need to tell TypeScript that this `Add` type will always be a `number` instead of relying on TypeScript to learn that by itself.

For example, you can force this info by adding `& number`:

```typescript
type Add<Num1 extends number, Num2 extends number> =
    [...BuildArray<Num1>, ...BuildArray<Num2>]['length'] & number
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^
```

or have any kind of type checks.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgSwDYBMCCAnDBDEAeAWACgpSoAZCAOwHNgALKCAD2GpQGcoq4BbAIwgYANFGJkoAUSTQAvFDhUA1lQD2AdyqjxZTBiat2XRSo1UA2gF0o8q8QB8NqHvMByGbQavrLNlU4U1HSMOhKkAPzOWGIkYaQAXLCIqHq4eJSe9KLSEKLmAHSFetkylvYA3MSgkFAAsiCpIE7wyOhYaQDMjgD03VDV0PWNTuYmapqiY2aTyuNUlsRV4NBoKCh4AHJ8AIwGfgE8AkKiW7wATHtG3HyCGI7yoVAFhS0p7fin2-aihfmvbTgPnwzvZLG4PMFvFAAGTXI4YYi9KCAJCJUWj0RjMVjsTicQA9AmEglLGqrFAAJQgHDgSGATjJeDOogArD0+gNnGtKdTaU4AOyLIgc2o04AIMBIIG8Xa+K6HW4nYGXfxceXHKAAYVUijY+llKrhtycAAZRNzRcqDjchCb7o8tTqbfqAqczuFHubafFHiLaeLJZsdorzqIGQ6qLrRF9Q2tA9KzVTRfZ7CTBqL-SBPXT5L6xRL8AAWFls-rLOrp-NZpxnY1AA)

Answer (score 0):

This is because here you are extending with number

```
Counter extends number = 0, Result extends number = 0
```

and your `Add<num1, num2>` type returns a narrowed number.

For example: `type AddResult = Add<2, 5> // type AddResult = 7`

when you do `typeof AddResult`, the output would be 7 (for TS it is unknown) and not `number` and that's why the error occured.

Comment: This begs the question: How do you fix it? :-)

Comment: Also: Why would `Add` returning a narrowed number be a problem? It still `extends number`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgPATShAHsCA7AJgZyhgVwFsAjCAJwD4oBeKBAbgFgAoUSKALVtjgHZKDKAHphUODToB1APbkA1ngBWBHMCgAzAJYYIQA)

Comment: It extends number but what Add deduce is unknown yet. [...BuildArray<Num1>, ...BuildArray<Num2>]['length'] does not states that it will result into a number.